# on matlab, how can i plot centroid points on top of an rgb image?

Tags: matlab

i have a list of about 300 centroid points. these points are the centroids of the conncomps of a BW image that i have. Is there a way to plot the points of the centroids over the original rgb image?

Comment: What have you tried? Please show show us your attempt for solving the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No problem. Have this short script:

```
img = imread('rice.png');
bg = imopen(img,strel('disk',15));
img2 = img - bg;

mask = im2bw(img2, 0.19);
mask = bwareaopen(mask, 40);

cc = bwconncomp(mask, 4);
positionArray = regionprops(cc, {'Centroid'});
positionArray = struct2cell(positionArray);
positionArray = cellfun(@transpose, positionArray, 'UniformOutput',false);
positionArray = cell2mat(positionArray);

imshow(img);
hold on;
scatter(positionArray(1, :), positionArray(2, :), 200, 'g+');
```

You can vary the markersize and shape as you wish. The points in this case are stored as a 2 by n matrix with x coordinates in the first row ans y in the second.

First, the image itself is plotted using imshow. Then, scatter() is called. To put both items on the same set of axes, you have to call hold on.